# setting twitter timeline href

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter

I am trying to dynamically set the href field on my twitter timeline using javascript or jquery how can I do this?

```
 <a class="twitter-timeline" id="twitter" data-lang="en" data-theme="dark" data-link-color="#19CF86" href=""; data-chrome="noheader, nofooter, noborders, noscrollbar,transparent">Tweets by me</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setAttribute` function. It sets an attribute of the selected element to whatever value provided by the user

```js
var link="www.link.com";
document.querySelector("#twitter").setAttribute("href",link)
console.log(document.querySelector("#twitter").getAttribute("href"))
```

```html
<a class="twitter-timeline" id="twitter" data-lang="en" data-theme="dark" data-link-color="#19CF86" href=""; data-chrome="noheader, nofooter, noborders, noscrollbar,transparent">Tweets by me</a>
```

Comment: thanks - any idea how it can be reloaded to show the change?

Comment: what do you mean by reloaded?

Comment: if I set that on document load it doesn't show the timeline on the page - so I assume it needs a reload/refresh or something? (using asp.net, c#)

Comment: onload you have to first change the link and add a trigger like a click to show the timeline. no need for refresh